# MYSQL Permission: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost

Tags: mysql, debian, permissions

Got a problem with a mysql server installation on Debian. (Not my server so I have no idea what caused this...)

Installing new applications that add a database fail with error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I can log in with the user, I've flushed permissions...

Then I can across this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-users-full-privileges

But when I try to stop mysql, it fails with

`error: 'Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debian use debian-sys-maint account for management (start/stop etc.).
Credentials are stored in **/etc/mysql/debian.cnf** - check if all are valid.

Comment: What to do if they are not ?

Comment: @Loenix what do you mean by "if they are not"?

Comment: Wow it was a long time ago...
If they are not in this file, I guess.

Comment: @Loenix Read my answer then, where I have a suggestion to reset those credentials.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of restoring the `debian-sys-maint` user.  Most easy to do is to reconfigure package `mysql-server-5.5`.  That if you know the password for the `root` user of MySQL, you can try to restore the user and its password in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

To restore MySQL:s `root` password (or any MySQL-users password) you can use the `debian-sys-maint` account.  You need to run `mysql` to get the password for the `debian-sys-maint` account.

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('secret') WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> QUIT;
```

So, **never** remove the user `debian-sys-maint`, as it is used in Debian to administrate MySQL (shut it down, roll logs, upgrade packages, check existans of `root` user in MySQL, set new `root` user password etc).

Comment: In my case i just `sudo killall mysqld` then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`, Now everything is ok.

Comment: `sudo killall mysqld` then run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.2` is what fixed it for me

Comment: One should stop the service, not kill the daemon.  And killing the server will get you unnecessary down time when the database is not accessible.

Comment: @Anders If I have data in databases, Can I use this `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` command ? it will just reconfigure root or data will be lost? Actually I have root password but when I run `service mysql status` it gives error given in the question

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya you should have backups of the data in your database, in all cases. :-) But it is a long time since I used `mysql`, I use `mariadb` and `postgresql` instead.  Should work without reseting the data, just change the administration password.  The `root` password is not used.
Also, adjust for the package you have installed, it might not be 5.5 any longer.